# How to check if model a has a User in it?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128) #actual creator's name
```

In a html page I want to check if Profile model has current logged in user in it?

I am using this line

```
{% if Profile.objects.filter(user=user).exists() %}
```

I know this is wrong, I am beginner to Django and web development. Could some one help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't write business logic (and therefore no queries as well) in the templates. Such logic belongs in the views. Django templates have deliberately a syntax that makes it harder to make calls, etc. to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try implementing this in views.

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py:

```
if request.user == profile.user:
    # your code
```

Or in your template:

```
{% if request.user == profile.user %}
    # your code
{% endif %}
```